# Grant select on function does not seem to work

Tags: sql-server

I have a user A that owns a Schema, let's call it A as well.
Another user B owns schema B.

User A have a Inline function, that returns a dataset from a table "A.Table".

Now I just want user B to use those functions without given select ability on the actual table to user B.

Normally that seems to work, but for some reason I'm not sure why GRANT select on the function under Schema A to the user B does not work.
Can somebody put some light on this issue?

Comment: What's "does not work"? Is there an Error message? Please also show your used queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the function is owned by user A (ownership chaining, permissions on the table are not checked if function and table have the same owner)

```
--user A and schema A (owned by user A)
create user A without login
go
create schema A authorization A
go

--permissions to user A, create table&function
grant create table to A
go
grant create function to A
go

--user B
create user B without login
go

--user A
execute as user = 'A'
go

create table A.testtable(id int)
go

insert into A.testtable(id) values(1),(2);
go

create function A.testfunc()
returns 
table
as
return
(   
    select *
    from A.testtable
)
go

grant select on A.testfunc to B;
go

revert
go

--user B
execute as user = 'B'
go

--ownership chain, function and table in the function owned by the same user A (user A created the function)
select *
from A.testfunc()
go

revert
go

--change ownership of function, function is owned by dbo
alter authorization on A.testfunc to dbo
go

grant select on A.testfunc to  B
go


--try again as user B
execute as user = 'B'
go

--permission violation
--ownership chain broken: function and referenced table (A.testtable in the function) are not owned by the same user...
select *
from A.testfunc()
go

revert
go
--cleanup
drop function A.testfunc
go
drop table A.testtable
go
drop schema A
go
drop user A
go
drop user B
go
```